# How do I update my database generated pg_basebackup through WAL files?

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore, postgresql-9.3, write-ahead-logging

Following on from [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/115007/7788)...

I have a backup generated by pg_basebackup regularly, I would update it through the WAL files.

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

See [the documentation on point-in-time recovery and WAL archiving](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/continuous-archiving.html) for how to manage this.

Short version:

- Set `archive_mode = on` in master
- Set an `archive_command` in master that stores the WAL archives in a location accessible to the replica
- Create the replica from a `pg_basebackup`
- Create a [`recovery.conf`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/recovery-config.html) on the replica that sets a `restore_command` to fetch the archived WAL. You may also want to set a `recovery_target_time` if you wish to stop replay at a certain point.
- Start the replica and let it replay WAL

You may find tools like [pgbarman](http://www.pgbarman.org/) useful as well.

Comment: There is a tool like pgbarman for windows?

Comment: Not that I know of, not on Windows. Most of the PostgreSQL infrastructure continues to focus more on Linux and Mac OS X. Support for Windows may be added to a future version of Barman, I know they're talking about it. In the mean time you'll have to use your own scripts/tools. [WAL-E](https://github.com/wal-e/wal-e) might work on Windows, though, I haven't checked.

Comment: Is there a script I can do the restoration?